# I have an unknown problem with my If/Elif/Else loop

Tags: python

I'm working on a choose your own adventure but I have run into a problem where no matter what I choose it will always take me down the path where I choose right. I was wondering if anyone could help me figure out what's wrong. I just got into coding so this would really help me out.

Here is the Code

"""

```
go1=()
go2=()
go3=()
go4=()
go='left'
print("Welcome to 'The Adventures of Cow'.")
print()
print("You are a cow you find yourself stranded on a deserted island in the middle of a vast blue ocean.")
print("To your right, you see a deep dark cave  and to your left you there is a forest of large palm trees.")
go=input("Would you like to go right or left? ")
print()

list=[]


if go =='right'or'Right'or'r' or 'R'or'RIGHT':
  list.append(go)
  print("You slowly walk to the mouth of the cave and stare into the darkness, then you take another step and all the light behind you is gone.")
  print("You take a look around you the walls are etched with odd glowing blue symbols, you are unable to decipher them but they somehow glow without giving off any light which you find strange.")

  print("All the sudden the walls begin to crumble and behind them are 9 wooden doors, all the same, striped dark wood with golden handles the exact size of your hoofs.")
  go1=input("Which door will you pick:1-9. ")
  print()
  if go1==1 or 3 or 5 or 7 or 9:
    list.append(go)
    print("When you walk through door {} the world begins to spin and you are transported back to ANCIENT GREECE!!?!".format(go))
    print("You stroll the streets of the great city of Athens until you are stopped by a man dressed in white and gold robes. He grabs a lead and guides you to a temple where he bathes and feeds you. When you are done eating he guides you into a throne room where you are sat upon the mighty throne looking over the large sprawling city.")
    print("All of the sudden 2 men come up behind you and grab your legs and drag you down a cold stone ramp into a dungeon.")
    print("On the walls, you see all sorts of weird machines and tools.")
    go2=input("The two that stick out the most are a large power drill and an unnaturally large soup spoon. Which do you take the drill or the spoon? ")
    print()
    if go2=="spoon" or "Spoon":
      list.append(go)
      print("When your captors are not looking you shimmy over and grab the spoon, as you pick up the spoon a weird golden orb floats out of the wall behind it.")
      print("The orb begins to speed up until it sits in the scoop of the spoon. You contemplate eating because it looks so tasty.")
      go=input("Will you eat the magic orb?")
      print()
      if go3== "yes" or "y" or "YES" or "Y":
        list.append(go)
        print("You bring your mouth closer to the orb and you comp it. Suddenly a bright light flashes, when your vision clears you to take off the VR headset in disappointment because you lost the game again.")
      elif go3 == "no" or "n" or "No" or 'N':
        list.append(go)
        print("You decided to resist the urge to eat it. Instead, you launch it into the far wall shattering a hole through it. On the other side of the wall, you see a massive ever-expanding dessert. It looks like chocolate cake with vanilla frosting. Yum!")
        print("You walk onto the cake and it folds out from beneath you dropping you into darkness.")
        print("Than the screen flashes 'Simulation Over'")
      elif go2=="drill" or "Drill":
        print("You pick up the drill and when your captors walk out of the room you unscrew the shelves that all the tools were on. The tools come clattering down making a large cloud of dust when the cloud clears behind the shelves is a giant gold key you reach out and grab it.")
        print("Suddenly your screen flashes green with gold letters reading congratulations YOU WIN'.")
      else:
        print("Simulation Over Retry.")
  elif go1 == 2 or 4 or 6 or 8:
    print("You walk towards door {} and step over the threshold.".format(go))
    print("When you get on the other side of the door you find yourself in a dark black room with code scrolling down into an abyss.")
elif go=='left' or 'Left' or 'l' or 'L' or 'LEFT':
  print("You walk into the dense forest, as you continue to walk deeper into the woods the path you were on starts to fade away until you are completely lost. No idea where you came from or where you are going.")
  print("As the sun begins to set you to wander around to find somewhere to sleep but as your walking, you get caught up in a net that was buried under some grass.")
else:
  print("retry")
```

"""

Comment: There are no loops in this code.  You meant "if/elif/else" statement, not loop.

Comment: As the duplicate explains, `if x == y or z:` is equivalent to `if (x == y) or z`, i.e. it will always be true if `z` is true (which is the case for strings).  Change it to `if x == y or x == z:`, or alternatively `if x in (y, z):`

Comment: You can also do `if go.lower() in ('r', 'right')` if you don't want to add so many equal signs.